# How to disable another select option when i get value of cash from a select option

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have this code i want to enabled or disable a certain select box for transaction.
I don't know what code is correct for this one hope you can lend me a hand.

```html
<select id="paymenttype" class="paymenttype" name="input-paymenttype"  onChange="changetextbox()">
 <option value="Cash">Cash</option>
 <option value="Installment">Installment</option>
</select>

<select id="paymentterms" class="" name="input-paymentterms" disabled="true">
 <option value="3">3x</option>
 <option value="4">6x</option>
 <option value="6">12x</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changetextbox()
{
 var e = document.getElementById("paymenttype");
  var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    if (value == "Cash") {
       alert('I need to disable payment terms');
           } 
     else{
   alert('I need to enable payment terms');
     document.getElementById("paymentterms").disable =='false';
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. It would be useful if you could edit the question to indicate exactly what you want to happen, what is happening in practice, and any error messages. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to remove attribute:

```
document.getElementById("paymentterms").removeAttribute("disabled");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.removeAttribute()` you can check it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute)

```js
  function changetextbox()
    {
     var e = document.getElementById("paymenttype");
      var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        if (value == "Cash") {
           alert('I need to disable payment terms');
               } 
         else{
       alert('I need to enable payment terms');
         document.getElementById("paymentterms").removeAttribute('disabled');
        }
    }
```

```html
    <select id="paymenttype" class="paymenttype" name="input-paymenttype"  onChange="changetextbox()">
     <option value="Cash">Cash</option>
     <option value="Installment">Installment</option>
    </select>

    <select id="paymentterms" class="" name="input-paymentterms" disabled="true">
     <option value="3">3x</option>
     <option value="4">6x</option>
     <option value="6">12x</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for the answer. I tried and test all your answer. It is quite impressive I finish it with your help. So i decided to paste the final code here.

```
     <select id="paymenttype" class="paymenttype" name="input-paymenttype"  onChange="changetextbox()">
      <option value="Cash">Cash</option>
      <option value="Installment">Installment</option>
   </select>

    <select id="paymentterms" class="" name="input-paymentterms" disabled="true">
      <option value="3">3x</option>
      <option value="4">6x</option>
      <option value="6">12x</option>
    </select>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function changetextbox()
    {

        var e = document.getElementById("paymenttype");
        var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        if (value == "Cash") {
           document.getElementById("paymentterms").disabled = true;  
               } else
                {
            document.getElementById("paymentterms").disabled = false;  

        }
    }
    </script>
```